# Como itero un arreglo en Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, foreach, ngfor

hago una peticion get y obtengo datos de una DB

```
this.lineasService.getLineas(URL).subscribe(resp => {
      this.result = resp;

      //  this.dataL = this.result?.Rowsets.Rowset[0].Row;

      this.result.Rowsets.Rowset.forEach(element => {
        element.Row.forEach(s => {
          this.data.push(s)
                    
        }); 
      });
    });
```

para hacerlo desde html utiilizo el `*ngFor="let item of data"`

```
<h1>{{item.dia}}</h1> <h1>{{item.semana}}</h1>
```

quiero poder usar los `item.dia y item.semana` pero desde typescript pero no se como

si imprimo en consola `console.log(data)` me sale object object

quiero saber de que forma puedo iterar a data y usar los valores de día y semana

De esta forma tengo el ROW

```
"Row" : [ 
        { "dia" : "lunes", "semana" : "2"}, 
        { "dia" : "martes", "semana" : "23"}, 
        { "dia" : "miercoles", "semana" : "12"} ]
```

Answer (score 1):

No se si es lo que buscas, pero para acceder a `dia` y `semana` debes hacer algo como esto en tu `.ts`:

```js
  data = [ 
    { "dia" : "lunes", "semana" : "2"}, 
    { "dia" : "martes", "semana" : "23"}, 
    { "dia" : "miercoles", "semana" : "12"} ]

  metodo(){
    /// Object.keys devuelve un array cuyos elementos son strings correspondientes a 
    /// las propiedades enumerables que se encuentran directamente en el object.
    let valor = Object.keys(this.data);
    let keys = Object.keys(valor);
    
    // Recorre la longitud del arreglo de objetos
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      let clave = keys[i];
      let acceso = valor[clave];
      console.log("Dia:", this.data[acceso].dia, "Semana:", this.data[acceso].semana)
    }
  }
```

Y en el `html` hice un botón para ejecutar el método, ya depende de tus necesidades, pero para acceder a lo que quieres así se lo hace. Lo que hice ahi te da como resultado esto:

```
Dia: lunes Semana: 2
Dia: martes Semana: 23
Dia: miercoles Semana: 12
```